# Ajuda na resolução do programa

Tags: c

Boa Noite,

Gostaria de colocar entre programa a dar em C, ma penso que isto eta a ler um ficheiro em txt e eu queria apenas que guarda-se e depois pudesse pesquisar selecionado essa opção.

Alguém consegue ajudar ?

É urgente quem poder ajudar agradecia muito.`

```
// Programa para guardar filmes.
// Menu iniciar que pergunta ao utilizador se deseja ler ou gravar


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//definir nome do arquivo

#define arquivo  "c:\\Filmes\\filmes.txt"

// funções utilizadas

int    menu           ();
void   ler            (FILE*);
int    gravar         (FILE*);
int    escrever_dados (FILE*);

int main(void)
{
//reservar espaço na memoria;
FILE *file = (FILE*)malloc(sizeof(file));

int select = 0;

while (select==0)
{
    //Escolha das funções do menu;
    //Aqui a função menu retorna o dado selecionado e executa a respectiva função;
    //Vai executar enquanto o menu não retornar o valor 3;
    switch(select = menu())
    {
    case 1:
        ler(file);
        break;

    case 2:
        gravar(file);
        break;

    case 3:
           return 0;
    default:
        break;

    }
}
return 0;
}
int menu()
{
printf("\n Digite uma das opcoes:\n   ler, gravar ou fim:");

char palavra [50];

//Espera pela palavra inserida pelo teclado e guarda a mesma na variavel "palavra"
scanf("%s",palavra);
//limpa o buffer do teclado;
fflush (stdin);
//converter todas as letras da variavel para maiusculas;
strupr(palavra);

//Ira aparecer entao a palavra digitada;
//Caso não seja a que se pretende ira retornar '0';
//Ira voltar ao menu para que o utilizador volte a inserir nova opção;
if        (!strcmp(palavra, "LER")     ==1)  return 1;
else if   (!strcmp(palavra, "GRAVAR")  ==1)  return 2;
else if   (!strcmp(palavra, "FIM")     ==1)  return 3;
else                                         return 0;

}

void ler (FILE*file)
{
  system    ("cls");
  printf    ("\n\n");

  file     = fopen (arquivo,"r");

  // Se o arquivo não abrir ira retornar 0, entao o negado(!) e para inverter e entrar na condição para mostrar a mensagem de erro.
  if (!file)
  {
   printf("\n\n Arquivo não encontrado!\n\n");
  }
  else
  {
   char c;

   //Verifica se o primeiro arquivo e igual a EOF(-1), o que indica o final do arquivo;
   if((c = getc (file))==EOF)
   {
       printf("Arquivo esta vazio!");
   }

   //Faz a leitura do arquivo carater a carater e mostra no ecra ate ao fim;
   while((c = getc(file))!= EOF)
   {
       printf("%c",c);
   }
  }
  //pausa
  getchar();
}

int gravar (FILE *file)
{
// "a": insere no fim; se não existir arquivo ele criara com "w";
if( (file = fopen(arquivo, "a") )||(file = fopen(arquivo,"w")))

{
    while(escrever_dados(file)){}
    return 0;
}
}

int escrever_dados(FILE *file)
{
char       codigo[20];
char       filme [20];
char       genero[20];
char       sair  [20];

printf     ("\n\nCodigo:");
//limpa buffer do teclado;
fflush      (stdin);
//captura a string;
gets        (codigo);
//copia a string para a variavel sair;
strcpy      (sair, codigo);
//comparar valor da string com a palavra FIM, caso seja = sai e retorna o valor '0';
// caso sejam diferentes então continua;
if(!strcmp(strupr(sair),"FIM")) return 0;

printf    ("Filme:");
fflush    (stdin);
gets      (filme);
strcpy    (sair, filme);

if(!strcmp(strupr(sair),"FIM")) return 0;

printf    ("Genero:");
fflush    (stdin);
gets      (genero);
strcpy    (sair, genero);

if(!strcmp(strupr(sair),"FIM")) return 0;

fprintf    (file,"\nCodigo:%s",codigo);
fprintf    (file,"    Filme:%s",filme);
fprintf    (file,"        Genero:%s",genero);

return 1;


}`
```

Comment: Creio que existam muitos problemas em seu código. Começo com: qual o significado que pretende com `FILE *file = (FILE*)malloc(sizeof(file));`?

Answer (score 2):

Boa noite, seu código há alguns erros, então o texto vai ser um pouco longo...

**Protótipos das funções**

Começo pelos protótipos de suas funções:

```
int    menu           ();
void   ler            (FILE*);
int    gravar         (FILE*);
int    escrever_dados (FILE*);
```

Tire os espaços entre os parênteses e o nome delas, também diminua o espaço entre o tipo de retorno com o nome, assim fica mais organizado:

```
int menu(void);
void ler(FILE*);
int gravar(FILE*);
int escrever_dados(FILE*);
```

Outro problema é nos argumentos delas, repare que você esqueceu de colocar a variável, você apenas colocou o tipo. O protótipo precisa ficar assim:

```
int menu(void);
void ler(FILE *file);
int gravar(FILE *file);
int escrever_dados(FILE *file);
```

Agora os protótipos podem usar um ponteiro para arquivos, antes não podiam por que não estavam declarados.

**Declaração de ponteiro para aquivo**

Nessa parte do código você não precisa usar o malloc:

```
FILE *file = (FILE*)malloc(sizeof(file));
```

Quando você faz `FILE *file;` o ponteiro para arquivo já é criado. Criar um ponteiro para o arquivo usando a `malloc()` só seria útil caso o ponteiro estivesse encapsulado em outro arquivo, mas como esse não é o caso então apenas faça isso:

```
FILE *file = NULL;
```

Deixar o ponteiro igual a `NULL` não é obrigatório, mas isso pode evitar você a usar ponteiros apontando para lugares desconhecidos na memória... Então recomendo você sempre igualar a `NULL` ponteiros não usado no momento.

**Variável select**

A variável `select` é meio que inútil no seu código, pois o retorno da função `menu()` pode ser usada sem problema no switch:

```
switch(select = menu()) // Isso dá no mesmo
switch(menu()) // que isso
```

**fopen()**

Não é necessariamente um erro, mas o `fopen()` retorna NULL quando falha.
Mas acho que seu código ficará mais elegante com:

```
if(file != NULL)
/* Você ainda pode otimizar espaço ao fazer isso */
if((file = fopen(arquivo,"r")) == NULL) return /* numero com erro */; /* E aqui pode encerrar a função/programa em caso de erro, pode usar um return para sair da função com erro */

/* Aqui será ativado em caso de sucesso */
```

**Esquecimento de fechar o arquivo**

No final da função `ler()` você esquece o `fclose(nome_do_arquivo)` para fechar o arquivo. Lembre-se que em C os dados não vão diretamente para o arquivo de disco e sim para a stream, o `fclose` é para avisar para o programa que todas as alteração naquele arquivo já terminaram e ele pode fechar e descarregar os dados lá, caso não faça isso então há possibilidades de perder os dados...
Você também esquece o `fclose` na função `gravar()`... Exemplo de como ficaria o `fclose()` em seu código:

```
fclose(file);
```

**fflush(stdin)**

`fflush()` têm o comportamento indefinido quando o argumento é `stdin`, ou seja, pode funcionar, pode não funcionar, ou pode ocorrer outras coias... Mesmo que funcione no seu PC eu recomendo não usar.

Uma solução para resolver esse problema que alguns recomendam é o `setbuf(stdin, NULL)`, mas esse comando não funciona em todos os computadores. Não vou entrar em muitos detalhes, pois questões de como limpar o buffer já foram discutidas muito, dê uma pesquisada depois. A solução que eu te apresento é a seguinte:

```
void limpar_buffer(void)
{
    char lixo;
    do
    {
        lixo = getchar();
    }while(lixo != '\n');
}
```

Escrevi ela de forma bem didática para você entender, mas é possível compactar essa função. Use ela sempre que você tiver certeza que há lixo no buffer.

**Leitura do teclado com gets ou scanf("%s")**

Essas função não servem para ler strings do teclado, pois elas não têm necessariamente um limite de caractere para ser lido, ou seja, se o usuário escrever algo com 50 caracteres e a string tiver apenas 20 de tamanho então 30 caracteres serão lidos e colocados em algum lugar na memória (provavelmente nas posições seguintes de seu vetor, isto é, v[21], v[22], ..., v[30], considere que a partir de v[21] não são partes de seu vetor). Esse problema é chamado de overflow, dê uma pesquisada depois.

Para resolver o problema a maioria recomenda o uso do `fgets(variavel_que_ficara_a_string, tamanho_da_string, stdin)`. Exemplo de uso:

```
char nome[20];
fgets(nome, 20, stdin);
```

Dessa forma você coloca um limite de 20 caracteres para serem lidos

**Problemas do fgets com a função de limpar buffer que eu recomendei**

Eu particulamente não recomendo o uso do `fgets`, por alguns motivos, o principal e que de fato vem ao caso é que ele tem um problema com o buffer.

Bem, quando o `fgets` ler menos caracteres ou a quantidade esperada então ele não deixa lixo no buffer e isto é ótimo, mas se o usuário digitar uma quantidade maior então os caracteres que não entrarem no vetor/string ficarão como lixo de memória. Teste o código abaixo para ver:

```
char nome[5], n[5];
fgets(nome, 5, stdin);
fgets(n, 5, stdin);
printf("%s \n", nome);
printf("%s \n", n);
```

No código acima digite nomes com menos de 5 caracteres e observe a saída, depois digite um nome com 6 ou mais caracteres e perceba que o lixo que ficará será atribuído ao segundo fgets.

A primeira solução para resolver isso é usar a função de `limpar_buffer()` que eu recomendei, mas com isso teremos um problema. O problema é que a função lmipar_buffer() irá abrir a entrada do teclado caso o buffer estiver limpo e isso iria causa um "pause" no programa, e isso não é o que queremos. Pelo fato de não ser possível prever se o fgets deixará lixo no buffer então não podemos usar o limar_buffer junto com o fgets.

Uma solução é criar a própria função para ler uma string:

```
void ler_string(char *nome, int tamanho)
{
    char letra, i = 0;
    do
    {
        letra = getchar();
        if(letra != '\n' && i < tamanho - 1)
        {
            nome[i] = letra;
            i++;
        }
    }while(letra != '\n');
    nome[i] = '\0';
}
```

A função acima pode ser compactada, mas escrevi assim para ficar mais fácil o entendimento dela. Essa função nunca deixará lixo no buffer independente do que o usuário digitar.

**Problema em usar o getchar para pausar o programa**

Muitos usam o `getchar()` como uma alternativa para o `system("pause")`, é uma ótima alternativa caso queira dar um pause para evitar o fechamento da janela quando o programa acaba, mas se usado no meio do programa o `getchar()` pode deixar um lixo no buffer e trazer um comportamento não esperado. Exemplo:

```
printf("Pressione enter para continuar... \n");
getchar();
printf("Digite um caractere: ");
scanf("%c", &n);
```

No programa acima se o usuário digitar enter então tudo bem, mas caso digite algo como aofhdskajfe aperte enter então o a será "excluído" e o resto ficará como lixo no buffer, isto é, o scanf iria ler o "o" e isso não é o que queremos. fora que o lixo pode ser lido em uma string sem a gente esperar. Uma solução simples para isso é usar a função `limpar_buffer()` para pausar a tela, ela sempre pausa a tela quando não há lixo no buffer (por isso não se dá bem com o fgets como mencionei).
O código acima ficaria assim:

```
printf("Pressione enter para continuar... \n");
limpar_buffer();
printf("Digite um caractere: ");
scanf("%c", &n);
```

Esses são os principais problemas que encontrei no seu código, pode haver mais, não sei. Faça as alterações e veja. Eu não testei com as alterações que mencionei pois usei muito tempo analisando seu código e escrevendo essa resposta e por isso estou meio cansado. Mas espero ter ajudado em algo. Caso ainda dê algum problema então avise.

Comment: Uma observação: nos protótipos das funções não é necessário colocar a variável, apenas o tipo já é suficiente.

Comment: Não sabia disso kkk, valeu pela observação!

Answer (score -1):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Apos a alterações ao abrir para tentar gravar e ao escolher o gravar isto volta ao "inicio" não consigo gravar nada.
Bata que o código de para gravar e depois ver o que gravei.

Comment: seria interessante considerar e utilizar a forma de edição da sua postagem, pois não é interessante colocar resposta sobre resposta..
Veja mais: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Tem como mandar o código depois das alterações?